# Window.location takes me to new page even when current form is not submitted completely.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect to different page after current form has been submitted but as it turns out, using `window.location` am diverted to new page very quickly and seems like my current form is not at all submitted.

Here the function that am using.

```
function updateImportJobTypeSettings()
{
    var importJob = document.getElementById("jobtype").value;
    var parser = document.getElementById("selectparser");
    var parserValue = parser.options[parser.selectedIndex].value;
    document.importJobManagmentForm.action="/admin/ImportJobManagment.jsp";
    document.importJobManagmentForm.requestAction.value="updateImportJobSettings";
    document.importJobManagmentForm.ImportJobParser.value=parserValue;
    document.importJobManagmentForm.ImportJobManagmentType.value=importJob;
    document.importJobManagmentForm.DivHidden.value="visible";
    document.importJobManagmentForm.submit();
    window.location = "/admin/ImportJobManagmentList.jsp"
}
```

My goal is that after ImportManagment.jsp page is submitted, I want to come back to ImportJobManagmentList.jsp page to see all data that were submitted to ImportJobManagment.jsp

Think to note here is that if I put debugger on then I do see that new job is created on JobList but if I go and try to update it, again new job is created rather than doing an update to the previous job.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line?  If the action is set, the forum might redirect itself.

Comment: if i comment out `window.location` line then page stay on ImportJobManagment.jsp, but I need to go to job list page which would also contain listing of job that i currently entered on job management page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition. You are trying to do two different actions! The form submission tries to go to one page and you are trying to redirect to another.

The redirect should happen from the server with the form submission, not from the clientside.

Comment: am trying to redirect after form is submitted, because i want to have all the data saved before redirecting to another page.

Comment: after form is submitted...am trying to go to different page, using window.location, why that is not correct.

Comment: Because that location line does NOT wait for the form to submit. It just fires. You should be doing that redirect from the *server* not the client.

Comment: now am doing something like `pageContext.forward("/admin/ImportJobManagmentList.jsp");`but it create new copy instead of updating the current job import.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form with an action (`document.importJobManagmentForm.action="/admin/ImportJobManagment.jsp";`) it will go to that page... but right after you tell the script to go to `"/admin/ImportJobManagmentList.jsp"` I would put the redirect right in ImportJobManagement.jsp under a specific condition.

Comment: but then all the form data are not submitted and on job list page, i do not see all data entered on previous form.

Comment: If you do all your code in ImportJobManage.jsp (like inserting in to DB) and then only after this you redirect to ImportJobManagement.jsp that is supposed to work.

`sendFormData => Page is redirected to ImportJobManagement.jsp => Get all input value => insert them in the Database => on finish redirect to ImportJobManagementList.jsp`

Comment: ok, in that case, if i understand it correctly, putting `window.location` after action, page will redirect to list page but since form was not submitted on previous page, no data will be save for that page, right?

Comment: so right now from the code, it should work because am calling window.location after submitting the form.

Comment: No, you remove the redirect from that page and you put it in ImportJobManagement.jsp after all your data has been processed.

What's happaning right, it's like Epascarello said, your doing 2 redirect at the same time but the window.location win  over your action

Comment: "window.location win over action", my understanding is that i need to have action so that all form data are saved and once everything is saved then i do submit, so all data goes to server and then i re-direct to another page using window.location

Comment: that's right !!! 
You should have a piece of code that is execute if and only if the form has been submit.

Comment: You should have a piece of code that is execute if and only if the form has been submit and in that piece of code you insert your redirect.